# UI Buttons in Unity, how to set a GUIStyle and a parent at the same time programmatically?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to generate UI buttons, and I'm having troubles. When I use
    GUI.Button(new Rect(...), texture, GUIStyle); 
I can set the button position, the GUIStyle and the texture (which is what I need), but I also need to set a Panel as the parent of every button, there's a method called 
    transform.setParent(game object); 
but GUI.Button returns a bool. I can create a 
    var b = new Button(); 
but I don't know how to give a GUIStyle, or a texture to an object Button. I need to solve the whole problem from a Csharp script. Set the button style and texture, and the button parent at the same time! Thanks.

Comment: If any of the answers worked for you, it would be helpful for others if you accept that answer. If not, feel free to comment on the answers given, or update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GUI class does not create any GameObjects in the scene graph, thus you can't define relations between them.

If you want actual UI objects that you can manipulate and put in a hierarchy, you'll have to use Unity's new GUI system (recommended).
If you don't want to use that, you'll have to calculate the relative positions of your UI yourself like

```
Vector2 parentPos = ...;
GUI.Label(new Rect(parentPos.x, parentPos.y, 10, 10), "Label");

Vector2 childPos = ...;
GUI.Button(new Rect(parentPos.x + childPos.x, parentPos.y + childPos.y, 10, 10), "Button");
```

As an alternative, GUI class also supports transformation matrices.

```
GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.identity;
Vector2 parentPos = ...;
GUI.Label(new Rect(parentPos.x, parentPos.y, 10, 10), "Label");

GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(parentPos, Quaternion.identity, Vector3.one);
Vector2 childPos = ...;
GUI.Button(new Rect(childPos.x, childPos.y, 10, 10), "Button");
```

This allows you to build a GUI scene graph yourself.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need just "the parent position", I need the parent GameObject, so I can ask him for their children.

Comment: Then you'll have to use a GameObject based UI, like Unity's new GUI.